# Why aren't some surfaces in a simple mesh subdividing while others won't?

Tags: mesh, faces

I've been having some issues subdividing a simple mesh. Normally I expect on subdividing a face the new intersecting lines are made with new polygons, but this isn't always the case. On one face the subdivide command will work but then selecting another face it doesn't work. However, if I select the edge select tool I can see that actually the loop around the face I tried to subdivide is indeed subdivided.

[image: This face has been subdivided]

[image: The edge is subdivided even though I performed the subdivide command on the face]

To produce this mesh I simply started with a cube and extruded a surface a few times. The smaller cubes on the far right are extrusions made after subdividing a surface successfully. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably, because it is already an ngon (face with >4 verts.)  Center verts or spanning edges will not be created when subdividing an ngon because there is no unambiguous way to create them-- no single way to connect the generated verts.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks for that. That's interesting because I thought it was just a rectangle with 4 edges.